# Software tools for orgainising education lab appointments

Tags: teaching, software, lab-management

Due to the Coronavirus situation it is required to adapt teaching activities to reduce risk of infection. Several courses have laboratory assignments that require physical presence. It is therefore necessary to reduce the number of students present by utilising all room availability. Due to the increased number of student groups and fragmented time slots it quickly becomes challenging to organise lab appointment times.

Are there any software tools for orgainising education lab appointments available?

Comment: What email/calendar program does your school use? Google G-Suite and MS Outlook both have appointment booking tools.

Answer (score 2):

If your institution has a Moodle server, you could use Moodle's "scheduler" activity.

If, on the other hand, you end up going for a solution hosted on a server outside your institution, such as @astronat's suggestion of a Doodle poll, be careful of local data protection laws.

Comment: You could use nuudel, which is a privacy-protective variant of doodle: https://nuudel.digitalcourage.de/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still in search for a system, but the [Clustermarket](https://www.clustermarket.com/) booking system could work well as it's made specifically for labs and has different roles such as admin and student with different access levels.