# Software recommendation for software for scheduling appointments with students

Tags: software

Due to the pandemic I need to make some appointments with students for teleconferencing. Ideally I want to plan 3 students in half an hour intervals. The idea is that I want to :

- have some group oral exam,
- I want them to organise themselves into the groups (instead of making a provisional table and then having to make schedule changes).
- I would like ideally a group of 3 people per 30 minute interval (the idea is that if somebody is late, I can start with the others and optimize my time).

I've used doodle in the past, but for this scenario is not suitable. I think although it has an option for 1 allotment per person, it does not have an option where I can set a group size per time allotment.

Ideally, I would like the service to be free (in the same sense as doodle). I've found this [link](https://www.g2.com/products/doodle/competitors/alternatives) which lists a few similar sites like:

- YouCanBook.me.
- Acuity Scheduling.
- SurveyMonkey.
- Google Forms.
- Calendly.
- TimeTrade.
- ...

I was wondering if anyone had experience on the software listed or another suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of <https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153928/software-tools-for-orgainising-education-lab-appointments>.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what type of software your university uses. Many schools use Google's G-Suite or Microsoft's Office. Both of these have features for booking times:

- Google's Calendar has an appointment feature ([link here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/190998?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop))
- Microsoft has similar tools ([link here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/scheduling-and-booking-app)).